# Button IsMouseOver Trigger is not working when Command is bound

Tags: c#, wpf

**Update:**
I found the problem. The Command is not in an executable state, so the Button is actually disabled. The problem is irrelevant to "myStyle".

**Expected behavior:**

I defined this style for my button, when the mouse is over my button, the opacity will change from 0.65 to 1.

**Code:**

```xml
<Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.65" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource SomeImage}" />
                    </Grid.Background>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
         </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

It works as expected: the opacity of Button changes from 0.65 to 1 when I hover my mouse over it, until I bind the Command Property like this:

```xml
<Button Command="{Binding SelectScenarioCommand}"
        Style="{DynamicResource myStyle}">
</Button>
```

**Actual Behavior:**

After I bind my Command, the opacity value stays unchanged (0.65) when I put my mouse over the button.

Comment: Don't use DynamicResource unless you want to change the Style during runtime. StaticResource lookup behavior has significantly better performance. You have a typo. The style's key is "myStle" and the reference is "myStyle". If this is a copy&paste error then you must provide more context because the currently posted code is absolutely fine (except for the mistyped of the resource key). It would then also be very helkpfuil if you could get more into details in regards of *"it works until"*. Like what exactly is the faulty behavior. Is the button disabled? Is only the opacity not changing?

Comment: @BionicCode. I tried StaticResource, it still does not work, so I believe it's irrelevant. "myStle" is a typo and I have corrected it in the question. I have added details in regards of "it works until".

Comment: @BionicCode. When I add the details as you suggested, I found the problem. The Command is not in an executable state, so the Button is actually disabled. The problem is irrelevant to "myStyle". Thanks!